# Setting up a LAN with multiple APs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I need to setup a network, and I guess I need some advice.

Basically, the physical setup is like this:

- Our house has two floors.
- Telephone connection is at 2nd floor.
- No wired connection between 1st and 2nd floor possible (without drilling a big hole or something like that).

Now I want to provide LAN and wireless networking on both floors. My first step was to attach a FritzBox to the telephone connection on 2nd floor, which provides LAN and wireless network connections. This works. So far, so good.

Unfortunately, the wireless signal is not strong enough for 1st floor, and as said before, I can not just use a LAN cable from 2nd to 1st floor. So my idea was to use a powerline adapter (Devolo DLAN) to connect 1st and 2nd floor. This works as well.

Thanks to the DLAN module I now have one ethernet port on 1st floor - but I'd like to have wireless network here as well. And this is where my problem starts …

I'd like to use a Linksys WRT54G router for wireless access on 1st floor, but I don't know how to configure it correctly. Basically, I guess I need it to work in repeater mode (if there is such a thing?).

What's important is that I don't want to have two separate networks, as e.g. we have a network-enabled printer on 2nd floor, and I'd like to use it via ethernet from 1st floor as well.

Any advice on how to configure the Linksys router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Repeater mde* does exist, but it is not what you wish to use.

1) Connect a pc to a LAN side port on the Linksys, from this pc open a Web Browser and go the Linksys GUI page (if your pc has address 192.168.1.3, for instance, the Linksys will be 192.168.1.1, thus in your Browser you will open the Web page

```
   http://192.168.1.1
```

but you will have to check the address yourself, there is no guarantee that the correct IP address is 192.168.1.1).

2) Go to Wireless page, and configure the Wifi as you like it (name, password, security type, choose a channel which is distant from that of the 2nd floor network, and a different name too, btw); save changes.

3) Go back to the Basic setup page, where you will have to disable WAN connection, set a static IP address for router designed as follows if your 2nd floor router gives numbers in the range 192.168.0.0/24, then take something convenient like 192.168.0.2. Lastly, disable DHCP. Save settings, then turn Linksys off.

4) Turn Linksys off and on again, draw a cable from powerline adapter to LAN port on the Linksys, reboot pc.

You are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Just one question: If I use different names for the two wireless networks, I won't be able to access the network printer from both, will I?

Comment: @GoloRoden You will be able to print from anywhere. That's the whole point of turning off DHCP in the AP: this way, all components (pc, printer and whatnots) belong to the same subnet and they can access and be accessed from all other components.

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks, I didn't know that :-). I'll give it a try, and if it works, accept as answer.